# Can I update multiple records with 1 SQL statement, where update value depends on the record being updated?

Tags: sql, sql-update, records

Given that there are 2 tables:

1. STATES (holds the list of states available) - key field = STATE_ID. Another key is DOMAIN_ID, STATE_NAME. Thus, there are records with the same STATE_NAME but different DOMAIN_ID.
2. OBJECTS (holds a list of all the objects, each with its own state) - key field = OBJECT_ID. Also contains a field STATE_ID.

Suppose I have a list of about 1000 objects, which need to be updated to the state "CLOSED" in their respective domains.

For one single object (say OBJECT_ID 12345), I can use the SQL statement:

```
update OBJECTS
set STATE_ID =
(
  select STATE_ID from STATES
  where STATE_NAME= 'CLOSED'
  and DOMAIN_ID =
  (
    select DOMAIN_ID from STATES a, OBJECTS b
    where a.STATE_ID = b.STATE_ID and b.OBJECT_ID = 12345)
  )
) where OBJECT_ID = 12345
```

Is it possible to use one statement to update more than one object? The crux of the problem seems to be that I cannot get round defining the OBJECT_ID in two places in the SQL statement.

For obvious reasons, the following statement would not work:

```
update OBJECTS
set STATE_ID =
(
  select STATE_ID from STATES
  where STATE_NAME= 'CLOSED'
  and DOMAIN_ID =
  (
    select DOMAIN_ID from STATES a, OBJECTS b
    where a.STATE_ID = b.STATE_ID and b.OBJECT_ID in
    (
      select distinct OBJECT_ID from OBJECTS_TO_UPDATE
    )
  )
) where OBJECT_ID in (select distinct OBJECT_ID from OBJECTS_TO_UPDATE)
```

Could anybody give me a hint on what I could do to work round this?

Thank you.

Comment: As some RDBMS allow certain syntax that others don't, what are you using?  (Oracle, MySQL, etc?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use table name OBJECTS because it is in scope e.g.

```
UPDATE OBJECTS
  SET STATE_ID = (
                  SELECT STATE_ID 
                    FROM STATES
                   WHERE STATE_NAME = 'CLOSED'
                         AND DOMAIN_ID = (
                                          SELECT DOMAIN_ID 
                                            FROM STATES a, 
                                                 OBJECTS b
                                           WHERE a.STATE_ID = b.STATE_ID 
                                                 AND b.OBJECT_ID = OBJECTS.OBJECT_ID
                                         )
                 )
 WHERE EXISTS (
               SELECT * 
                 FROM STATES
                WHERE STATE_NAME = 'CLOSED'
                      AND DOMAIN_ID = (
                                       SELECT DOMAIN_ID 
                                         FROM STATES a, 
                                              OBJECTS b
                                        WHERE a.STATE_ID = b.STATE_ID 
                                              AND b.OBJECT_ID = OBJECTS.OBJECT_ID
                                      )
                 );
```

Comment: You've functionally changed what the OP wants to do.  Only a subset of the OBJECTS table need updating (Those with an OBJECT_ID in the OBJECTS_TO_UPDATE table)

Comment: @Dems: it was supposed to highligh how the table can be referenced in scope but for completeness (and overkill) I've updated my answer.

Comment: Umm, doesn't the WHERE clause just need to be as per the OPs?  `where OBJECT_ID in (select distinct OBJECT_ID from OBJECTS_TO_UPDATE)
`

Comment: @Dems: I'm only looking at the first query in the question (teach a man to fish and all that).

Comment: onedaywhen, thank you for your suggestion and it is tested to work. Regarding the comment by dems, I saw the original answer, worked out that the where clause needs to be updated and changed it for my test, so no harm done. I was just asking for somebody to point me in the right direction anyway, rather than for somebody to give me the exact SQL I need. But thanks for correcting your answer as it will help the other readers.

Answer (score 0):

**SQL Server, MS Access**, (MySQL?) solution:

I think this does the trick. You might want to replace the `UPDATE` and `SET` clauses with a `SELECT *` first, and check that the result set looks correct:

```
update o
set STATE_ID = s_closed.STATE_ID
from
   Objects o
      inner join
   States s_current
      on
         o.STATE_ID = s.STATE_ID
      inner join
   States s_closed
      on
         s_current.DOMAIN_ID = s_closed.DOMAIN_ID and
         s_closed.STATE_NAME = 'Closed'
      inner join
   OBJECTS_TO_UPDATE otu
      on
         otu.OBJECT_ID= o.OBJECT_ID
```

Comment: This should work in MS-SQL-Server, but not in Oracle (for example).  Totally depends on what RDBMS the OP is using I guess...

Comment: @Dems - true, I'll add a note at the top - but note that we're working with two different rows from the STATES table, and I think that matches what the OP has in their first query - so your answer needs a bit of work too :-)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about the structure of your tables, I can't be certain as to what SQL you need.  But the sub-query to get the new STATE_ID can (as onedaywhen said) reference the table you are updating...

For example...

```
update
  OBJECTS
set
  STATE_ID =
    (
      select
        NEW_STATE.STATE_ID
      from
        STATES    AS OLD_STATE
      inner join
        STATES    AS NEW_STATE
          ON NEW_STATE.DOMAIN_ID = OLD_STATE.DOMAIN_ID
      where
        OLD_STATE.STATE_ID = OBJECTS.STATE_ID
        AND NEW_STATE.STATE_NAME = 'CLOSED'
    )
where
  OBJECT_ID in (select distinct OBJECT_ID from OBJECTS_TO_UPDATE)
```

In this way, you can ensure that the sub-query returns only one STATE_ID for any given record in the OBJECTS table.